# jQuery: how to return list of categories?

Tags: jquery, html-table

In this table I have 1 checkbox per row. How to return the list of Categorynames from all the rows that are checked by the checkbox?

html:

```
<tbody>
    <table>
        <tr style="height: auto" role="row" class="jqgfirstrow">
            <td style="height: 0px; width: 55px;" role="gridcell">
            </td>
            <td style="height: 0px; width: 150px;" role="gridcell">
            </td>
            <td style="height: 0px; width: 150px;" role="gridcell">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1" id="1">
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_act" title="" style="text-align: center;" role="gridcell">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Catchecked" id="Catchecked"><input type="hidden"
                    value="false" name="Catchecked">
            </td>
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Name" title="Beverages" style="text-align: left;"
                role="gridcell">
                Beverages
            </td>
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Description" title="Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
                style="text-align: left;" role="gridcell">
                Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1" id="2">
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_act" title="" style="text-align: center;" role="gridcell">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Catchecked" id="Catchecked"><input type="hidden"
                    value="false" name="Catchecked">
            </td>
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Name" title="Condiments" style="text-align: left;"
                role="gridcell">
                Condiments
            </td>
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Description" title="Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
                style="text-align: left;" role="gridcell">
                Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1" id="7">
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_act" title="" style="text-align: center;" role="gridcell">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Catchecked" id="Catchecked"><input type="hidden"
                    value="false" name="Catchecked">
            </td>
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Name" title="Produce" style="text-align: left;"
                role="gridcell">
                Produce
            </td>
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Description" title="Dried fruit and bean curd"
                style="text-align: left;" role="gridcell">
                Dried fruit and bean curd
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1" id="8">
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_act" title="" style="text-align: center;" role="gridcell">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Catchecked" id="Catchecked"><input type="hidden"
                    value="false" name="Catchecked">
            </td>
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Name" title="Seafood" style="text-align: left;"
                role="gridcell">
                Seafood
            </td>
            <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Description" title="Seaweed and fish" style="text-align: left;"
                role="gridcell">
                Seaweed and fish
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Do you want an array of the string names? If not, then what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in some function whenever you need to collect the categories from the table :

```
var table = ...; // get the table DOMElement or jQuery object here
var categories = [];
$(':checkbox[checked]', table).each(function() {
    categories.push($(this).parent().next().text().trim());
});
//alert(categories);   // return an array of categories
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwpq9/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var cat = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').parent().next().map(function(){
                    return $(this).attr('aria-describedby')
              }).get()
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kAeCL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickhere').click(function() {
    var categories = [];
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        categories.push($(this).parent('td').next('td').text().trim());
    });
    alert(categories);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LvbDQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are going to do with each value that is checked, but the following will get the text that you are looking for.

```
$("table input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function()
  {
     console.log($.trim($("td[aria-describedby=jqgCategories_Name]", $(this).closest("tr")).text()));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find here complete solution for above query.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8w

**HTML**

```
<div class="input">
  <span>
    <input type="button" name="btnget" id="btnget" value="Get Categories"/>
  </span>
  <span id="result">
  </span>
</div>

<table>
  <tr style="height: auto" role="row" class="jqgfirstrow">
    <td style="height: 0px; width: 55px;" role="gridcell">
    </td>
    <td style="height: 0px; width: 150px;" role="gridcell">
    </td>
    <td style="height: 0px; width: 150px;" role="gridcell">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1" id="1">
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_act" title="" style="text-align: center;" role="gridcell">
      <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Catchecked" id="Catchecked">
      <input type="hidden"
      value="false" name="Catchecked">
    </td>
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Name" title="Beverages" style="text-align: left;"
    role="gridcell">
      Beverages
    </td>
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Description" title="Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    style="text-align: left;" role="gridcell">
      Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1" id="2">
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_act" title="" style="text-align: center;" role="gridcell">
      <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Catchecked" id="Catchecked">
      <input type="hidden"
      value="false" name="Catchecked">
    </td>
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Name" title="Condiments" style="text-align: left;"
    role="gridcell">
      Condiments
    </td>
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Description" title="Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    style="text-align: left;" role="gridcell">
      Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1" id="7">
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_act" title="" style="text-align: center;" role="gridcell">
      <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Catchecked" id="Catchecked">
      <input type="hidden"
      value="false" name="Catchecked">
    </td>
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Name" title="Produce" style="text-align: left;"
    role="gridcell">
      Produce
    </td>
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Description" title="Dried fruit and bean curd"
    style="text-align: left;" role="gridcell">
      Dried fruit and bean curd
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1" id="8">
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_act" title="" style="text-align: center;" role="gridcell">
      <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Catchecked" id="Catchecked">
      <input type="hidden"
      value="false" name="Catchecked">
    </td>
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Name" title="Seafood" style="text-align: left;"
    role="gridcell">
      Seafood
    </td>
    <td aria-describedby="jqgCategories_Description" title="Seaweed and fish" style="text-align: left;"
    role="gridcell">
      Seaweed and fish
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $(function() {
    $("#btnget").click(function() {
        $("#result").html("");
        var categories = new Array();
        $(".jqgrow").each(function() {
            if ($(this).find("td:first input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
                categories.push($(this).find("td[aria-describedby=jqgCategories_Name]").text().trim());
            }
        });
        if (categories.length > 0) {
            $("#result").html(categories.join(","));
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8w